# How to make a spark cluster ?

Tags: apache-spark

I've big physical machine with 16 CPUs , 256 GB RAM, 20 TB Hard disk. I just need to know what should be the best solution to make a spark cluster?

If I need to process TBs of data then 
1. Only one machine, which contain driver, executor, job tracker and task tracker everything. 
2. create 4 VMs and each VM should consist 4 CPUs , 64 GB RAM 
3. create 8 VMs and each VM should consist 2 CPUs , 32 GB RAM each

please give me your views/suggestions

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve actually. If you just want to calculate something you can just use Spark in local configuration mode (your option 1). If you create a cluster using VMs it will not make your actual code faster but you can practice how to configure Spark in different cluster modes :)

Comment: I just want to process the data with less time taken so want to know what could be the best way to distribute my cluster.

Comment: If you have only one physical machine it is better to use Spark in local mode as for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to Udemy teacher Frank Kane on [his tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/taming-big-data-with-apache-spark-hands-on), option 1 is better. There's really no point to setting up VM's on one machine in an attempt to emulate a cluster. When you're setting up your `SparkConf`, you can use `setMaster("local[*]")` to let it take advantage of all the cores on your laptop and distribute the work automatically, as it would on a cluster.

Comment: I see no reason for this answer to have been downvoted, as it seems correct and even provides a credible reference.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is the best in your case. If you start creating VMs then there will be network overheads because of merging of results from the parallel executions. Also based upon the specs you gave it appears that you will be creating VMs on the same machine. So this will also add additional overhead because of VM. Also x vms mean x OS kernels in RAM which instead can be used by spark worker. Besides spark can detect the cores on your machine and parallelize the operation by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 machine for maximum performance use local cluster.
Set the master as "`local[numthreads]`" Set the number of threads optimal for your job.

You Can start spark in local mode ie by setting `conf.setMaster("local[numthreads]")` in the code or by

using `--master local[numthreads]` while submitting the job.

If you start creating VMs then there will be network overheads , CPU and RAM wastage